# Get Application Icon's MD5 value

Tags: vb.net, icons, compare, md5

I want to be able to get an application's raw icon MD5 value.

I have no idea where to start using VB.Net.

Comment: You want to get the icon's MD5 value, or an icon by it's MD5 value?

Comment: I want to get the ICONS MD5, so extract the icon from the application, and get only that icons md5, not the applications.

Comment: Ok, I edited your question so it was explicit. I was confused reading it before. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the default application icon from an executable file, you can use [this code](http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet3236.htm)

After you got the Icon, save it into a file and use [this code](http://vbdotnetforum.com/index.php?/topic/407-get-md5-of-file/) to get its MD5. You don't actually have to save the file, just convert the icon into byte array and use it to convert to MD5 value.